# JS Pass data between methods

Tags: javascript, methods

I have two methods:

1. Gets a photo with an ID
2. Gets a collection of photos with an ID

I'm trying to get the response data to pass into the `savePhoto()` method so I'm able to trigger the download.

So far I've had no look, no matter what I try.

Any and all advice/feedback would be helpful.
Thank you.

Attempt 1

```
const unsplashAxios = require('./unsplashAxios');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

class Unsplash {

  constructor() {
    this.unsplash = null;
  }

  getPhoto(id){
    this.unsplash = unsplashAxios( `/photos/${id}`);
    this.unsplash.then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
    return this;
  }

  getCollection(id){
    this.unsplash = unsplashAxios(`/collections/${id}/photos`);
    this.unsplash.then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
    return this;
  }

  savePhoto() {
    // Get response data
    // const imgUrl = data.urls.raw;
    // const imgPath = `${data.id}.jpg`
    request('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571111937090-4452a4af8755?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEwNjE4NH0').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEwNjE4NH0.jpg'));
  }

}

myUnsplash = new Unsplash();
myUnsplash.getPhoto('PgHc0Ka1E0A').savePhoto();
myUnsplash.getCollection('62890').savePhoto();
```

Attempt 2

```
const unsplashAxios = require('./unsplashAxios');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

class Unsplash {

  constructor() {
    this.unsplash = null;
  }

  async getPhoto(id) {
    try {
      this.unsplash = await unsplashAxios(`/photos/${id}`)
      const response = this.unsplash
      savePhoto(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    return this;
  }

  async getCollection(id) {
    try {
      this.unsplash = await unsplashAxios(`/collections/${id}/photos`)
      const response = this.unsplash
      savePhoto(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    return this;
  }

  savePhoto(response) {

    console.log(response)

    // Get response data
    // const imgUrl = data.urls.raw;
    // const imgPath = `${data.id}.jpg`
    //request('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571111937090-4452a4af8755?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEwNjE4NH0').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEwNjE4NH0.jpg'));

  }

}

myUnsplash = new Unsplash()
myUnsplash.getPhoto('PgHc0Ka1E0A')
myUnsplash.getCollection('62890')
```

Comment: Call `savePhoto` from within the `then` portion of the appropriate request and get the values you need from the `response` object.

Comment: @JDunken would this be the best practice with doing this ? I'm not looking for a quick fix if there is a better more appropriate approach.

Comment: The only place the response data will be available is inside the `then` or possibly a `finally` block of the call. So you have to do it there. You can set the values directly inside the `then` block or call a function with the values required. Calling a function omits any data synchronicity issues.

Comment: @JDunken Ok, so I've tried rewriting the above but I'm still unable to receive the data within the savePhoto method. I get the following console error 'savePhoto is not defined'. Any thoughts ?